# Dynamic grouped bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a dynamic bar chart which updates on every iteration of a loop, but the chart only renders once the loop is completed. Can someone please help with this ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from IPython import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
from numpy.random import randn
%matplotlib inline
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
ax.set_xlabel("Load", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("People", fontsize=12)
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people, rotation=75)
fig.canvas.draw()
width = 0.4
for i in range(0,3):    
    p1 = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
    p2 = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
    df = DataFrame({'p1': p1, 'p2': p2})
    ax.barh(y_pos, df['p1'], width, color='red')
    ax.barh(y_pos + width, df['p2'], width, color='blue')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Add a `plt.show()` at every iteration?

Comment: Doesnt help. I am sure i am missing something simple though!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Problem was with %matplotlib inline statement and its placement. 
For interactive charts, its suggested to use %matplotlib notebook instead of inline. And its supposed to be placed before matplotlib is imported.

The following code worked!

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from IPython import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
from numpy.random import randn
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
ax.set_xlabel("Load", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("People", fontsize=12)
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people, rotation=75)
fig.canvas.draw()
width = 0.4
for i in range(0,3):    
    p1 = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
    p2 = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
    df = DataFrame({'p1': p1, 'p2': p2})
    ax.barh(y_pos, df['p1'], width, color='red')
    ax.barh(y_pos + width, df['p2'], width, color='blue')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```